# How to prevent language tags adding in iframe urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have iframes in my page. While clicking on button, I will be generating url and load to src of iframes.

My problem is the language tag `"/en-us/"` is adding in script and error showing in console that `"en is undefined"`

Script:

```
$(document).on("click", ".link", function (e) {
var url = "home/index"
e.preventDefault();
$("#container iframe").attr("src", url + "?name=" + $(this).attr("data-name") + "?action=" + $(this).attr("data-action"));
$(container).dialog("open");
});
```

In my console window:

```
$(document).on("click", ".link", function (e) {
   var url = "home/index"
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#container iframe").attr("src", url + "?name=" + 
   $(this).attr("data-name") + "?action=" / en - us / +$(this).attr("data-action"));
   $(container).dialog("open");
   });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <iframe>

    </iframe>
</div>

<div class="link" data-name="Test" data-action="load">
```

How to remove this characters from script or how to prevent this from adding in script ?

Comment: Where does the language tag appear: perhaps it would help to show the HTML after your script has run?

Comment: Please see In **my console window:** section 
$("#container iframe").attr("src", url + "?name=" + $(this).attr("data-name") + "?action=" / en - us / +$(this).attr("data-action"))

Comment: That's the JS code, not the result of that code.